# What is the difference between NSMutableDictionary and CFDictionaryRef?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to get the EXIF attachment from an image captured using AVCaptureDevice like this:

```
CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = (CFDictionaryRef)CMGetAttachment(buf, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);

NSMutableDictionary *exifAttachment = (__bridge NSMutableDictionary*)CMGetAttachment(buf, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
```

Both seem to return the same result, although the NSMutableDictionary one needs `__bridge` to cast the type. What are the differences between them? When should I use which?

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, `CFDictionaryRef` is non-mutable whereas `NSMutableDictionary` is mutable (can be modified).

You cannot replace one with another. However, `CFMutableDictionaryRef` can be converted to `NSMutableDicionary` and that conversion is toll-free bridged conversion. For `CFDictionaryRef`, equivalent object is `NSDicionary`.

If you are writing your program using pure C/C++, then use Core Foundation's `CFDicionary`. 
For Objective-C, you can use both.

Below these links can help you.

[Relationship between CFMutableDictionary and NSMutableDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439547/relationship-between-cfmutabledictionary-and-nsmutabledictionary)

[NSMutableDictionary vs CFMutableDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574296/nsmutabledictionary-vs-cfmutabledictionary)